# Why this C++ LinkedList statement is invalid?

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, linked-list

I'm new with C++, currently studying it for data structure. I saw this example on Pointers and I couldn't specify why it's invalid. I searched on Google but couldn't find the answer.

[image: The actual example]

The question:

```
Are the following expressions true or false
a.  head->next == ptr1     TRUE
b.  ptr1->next->data== 46      FALSE (Why!)
c.  ptr2->next == NULL     FALSE (Why!)
d.  head->data == 12       TRUE
```

Comment: What do you think `ptr1->next->data` should be?

Comment: I belive it will print `ptr1->next->data` will print `34`

Comment: And is 34 equal to 46?

Comment: Can't you put your finger on this picture and fallow respective arrow as each question describes?

Comment: I get it now, thank you so much guys I feel stupid now

Comment: ptr2->next points to the node that contains 75.

Comment: The slash at the end denotes a null pointer.

Comment: @Useless You did well piloting OP through understanding themselves. It seems a perfect answer according to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions Are you going to make it an answer? It seems even a useful demonstration of the "arrow and rectangle" tool, which I am a fan of. I.e. I would even consider it upvotable.

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing how to write a good, useful answer that is more than `34 != 46`. Anyone who feels inspired should go for it!

Comment: I would expect the answer would be an explanation on how to read such a diagram.

Answer (score 1):

> b.  ptr1->next->data== 46      FALSE (Why!)

`ptr1` points to the node whose `data` is `24`. That node's `next` points to the node whose `data` is `34`.  The node *after* that one is whose `data` is `46`.  So, `ptr1->next->next->data == 46` would be TRUE instead.

> c.  ptr2->next == NULL     FALSE (Why!)

`ptr2` points to the node whose `data` is `63`.  That node's `next` is not `NULL`, it points to the node whose `data` is `75`.  That node's `next` is `NULL`.  So, `ptr2->next->next == NULL` would be TRUE instead.